# Singletons and the Automation bridge

Tags: javascript, uno, uno-automation-bridge

The type [`com.sun.star.frame.Desktop`](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/singletoncom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1frame_1_1Desktop.html) is deprecated, and it is recommended to use the [`com.sun.star.frame.theDesktop`](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/singletoncom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1frame_1_1theDesktop.html) singleton instead.

Other language bindings support access to a singleton. In Java, [this thread](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/libreoffice/2016-September/075285.html) says the following works:

```
com.sun.star.frame.theDesktop.get(componentContext)
```

However, the `com.sun.star.frame` namespace isn't available under the Automation bridge; there is only the single entry point of the service manager:

```
var objServiceManager = new ActiveXObject('com.sun.star.ServiceManager');
```

**How can I acces this (and other) singletons?**

(Originally posted on [ask.libreoffice](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/127872/accessing-a-singleton/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Singletons are accessed using the `getByName` method on the script context, passing in a string path to the singleton:

```
'/singletons/com.sun.star.frame.theDesktop'
```

The Automation bridge exposes the script context at the `DefaultContext` property on the service manager:

```
var serviceManager = new ActiveXObject('com.sun.star.ServiceManager');
var desktop = serviceManager.defaultContext.getByName('/singletons/com.sun.star.frame.theDesktop');
```

(I was led to the solution by [this post](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=79489&p=365392#p365748) where the author is trying to automate OpenOffice using Delphi.)